# Statsmodels: Retrieve p-values when H0 is not zero

Tags: python, statsmodels

The post [Retrieve model estimates from statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522609/retrieve-model-estimates-from-statsmodels) shows that you can get a p-value for beta from a linear regression model using `model.pvalues`. To be specific, using the same example as in that post you could get it directly using `sm.OLS(df['y'], x).fit().pvalues[1]`. This would be under the assumption that `H0=0`. Let's say that I'd like to know if the slope of a linear model is significantly different from 1 instead? Is there a straight-forward way to adjust `H0`, and retrieve the p-value accordingly?

**Edit:  Example**

Building on the post above and the comment from Josef, here's a potential setup:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

# A dataframe with two variables
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 12
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=rows, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,150,size=(rows, 2)), columns=['y', 'x'])
df = df.set_index(rng)

x = sm.add_constant(df['x'])
model = sm.OLS(df['y'], x).fit()
model.summary()
```

**Output** (abbrevaited):

```
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const        176.6364     20.546      8.597      0.000     130.858     222.415
x             -0.3572      0.158     -2.261      0.047      -0.709      -0.005
==============================================================================
```

From `dir(model)` I've found `'wald_test'` and `'wald_test_terms'`. How could you use any(?) of these to test a hypotheses that beta = 1? `H0:beta=1, HA beta!=1`

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: use the t_test method and wald_test for joint hypothesis. Those are for null hypothesis that are linear restrictions on parameters.

Comment: @Josef, thank you for responding! Could I ask you to show this in detail? I've added a possible setup in the question.

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.t_test.html  has examples, e.g. `model.t_test('x=1')`

Comment: @Josef Would you like to write your comments up as an answer? If not, I guess I'll make an attempt in a while...