# Retrieving Values from Model Object

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

Im using following code to train my model

```
trip_model = sm.OLS(x_dependent, y_variables).fit()
```

and print summary as

```
trip_model.summary()
```

I just want to take only the following values out of Summary

```
F-statistic , coef
```

how to get it?

Comment: This is a statsmodel class, not related to scikit-learn. Removing that tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a particular value from the OLS-summary in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508158/how-to-extract-a-particular-value-from-the-ols-summary-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by the [`fit`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit.html) function is a [`RegressionResults`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html) structure. You can check the documentation to see how to access each particular value:

```
f_statistic = trip_model.fvalue
coef = trip_model.params
```

Comment: Yes., this link helped http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html